# How to see names for survey responses?

Tags: google-forms

How can I show the name or email address for responses to form survey in the results spreadsheet?  We want to see each other's responses but results sheets seem to be anonymous and only show time stamps of responses, but no identifier.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the top right hand corner of the screen, click the gear/cog icon to enter **Settings**:

[image]

2. Next, tick the box next to the option **Collect email addresses**:

[image]

3. Click **Save**.

Comment: works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Google Workspace users have an option in Google Forms to automatically record the email-address of the respondent but it's is limited to users of the same domain as the form owner <sup>1</sup>.

One option is to enable the option for collection email-address. This will add a question where the user should type an email-address.

Another option is to add a question asking for the name of the respondent or any other information to identify them properly.

---

**Footnotes**
<sup>1</sup>: [View & manage form responses - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a field asking for a name or email address from the respondents.

Google Forms provides an Email validation if you want to an email address field.

[image]

For email:

1. Select "text" for question type
2. Click "Advanced Settings"
3. Check "Data Validation"
4. Select "Text" and "Email Address"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a name/email-id field at the start of your survey. This helps identifying the responses.